# Gestures does not work for ListView Items on Android

Tags: android, listview, delphi, firemonkey, gesture

I want to use "LongTap" and "PressAndTap" gestures for **items** of a `TListView` in a FireMonkey multi-device application, I have set `OnGesture` event of `ListView` as below :

```
begin
 case EventInfo.GestureID of
  igiPressAndTap : begin
                    {...}
                   end;
  igiLongTap : begin
                {...}
               end;
 end;

 Handled := True;
end;
```

but when I test it on Android device, the `OnGesture` event does not get occurred

I have checked my desired gestures on `InteractiveGestures` property

I have tested with or without `GestureManager`

How can I set OnGesture for Listview`s Items ?

There is no any event like `OnGesture` for `TListViewItem` type

I`m using Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo

Comment: Did you setup gestures as instructed in [this doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey), including checking applicable `InteractiveGestures`?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes I did

Comment: Ok then you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Thanks for your help but I think everything is clear enough, Create a new multi-device project add a TListView on form, set OnGesture event and set InteractiveGestures checked, add some Items to listview run-time, this is the example that I have explained in the question post

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. A project that was developed in XE7, and worked fine, now against 10.3.2 Rio, the gestures are not being fired on double tap for android devices. The InteractiveGestures is filled. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I tested an application following the instructions in the [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey) provided by Tom, you need to set the gestures you want inside the Touch property in the Object Inspector.

[image]

In the OnGesture event the code just check if the GestureID is the Gesture I want to be executed.

```
procedure TfrmMain.listProdtsRotaGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case EventInfo.GestureID of
    igiLongTap:
      ShowMessage('longTap: ' + listProdtsRota.Selected.Index.ToString);

    igiPressAndTap:
      ShowMessage('pressAndTap: ' + listProdtsRota.Selected.Index.ToString);

    igiDoubleTap:
      ShowMessage('doubleTap: ' + listProdtsRota.Selected.Index.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Those link is the main document to work with gestures and I have done all of it but did not work. Which device you have tested on ? are you sure its working for "Items" of listview ?

Comment: I tested it in a Moto G5, Android 7.0, you need to add the `InteractiveGestures` in the Touch property of the list view, not the item, the OnGesture event is also from the list view, you can use `listView.Selected` to get the selected item. I edited the answer to show this